# Multiple particle systems for different objects in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game in Unity where you can shoot guns. I'm trying to make it so that if you shoot the ground a different particle system plays then when you shoot an enemy.

```
            Enemy enemy = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
            if (enemy != null)
            {
                enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
                GameObject impactGameObject = Instantiate(enemyImpactEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal));
                Destroy(impactGameObject, 0.5f);
            }
```

This code by itself works and plays a blood particle system when hitting the enemy. However, when I add this code:

```
            if(ground != null)
            {   
                GameObject groundImpactGameObject = Instantiate(groundImpactEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal));
                Destroy(groundImpactGameObject, 0.5f);
            }
```

It sort of works how I want it. The particle effect plays when I hit the ground but whenever I shoot the enemy it plays both the blood and ground particle system. Is there a way to avoid this obstacle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a bool and sample if an enemy is being hit, right now the only thing stopping the ground particles from playing is if the ground exists.

```
bool enemyBeingHit = false;

Enemy enemy = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
if (enemy != null)
{
   enemyBeingHit = true;
   enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
   GameObject impactGameObject = Instantiate(enemyImpactEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal));
   Destroy(impactGameObject, 0.5f);
} else {
   enemyBeingHit = false
}

if(ground != null && !enemyBeingHit)
{   
   GameObject groundImpactGameObject = Instantiate(groundImpactEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal));
   Destroy(groundImpactGameObject, 0.5f);
}
```